# Responsive Form in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

I am learning Bootstrap and am trying to implement it within a Ruby on Rails projects I have. I am using the bootstrap navbar and am trying to integrate that with rails. I have a search bar that I am trying to make responsive. I want the width of the search form to fill up the available space, and shrink/grow as the screen size changes. The navbar in bootstrap already has a lot of CSS styles applied to it and I feel like trying to add a feature like this to an existing navbar is difficult.

Here is the code for my form...

application.html.erb

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #228822;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!-- overriding to HTTP GET because turbolinks causes issues with pagination infinite scroll -->
      <%=link_to "The Pragmatic Bookshelf", store_index_path, :class => "navbar-brand", method: :get, style: "color:#bbffbb" %>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to t('.questions'), store_index_path, style: "color:#bbffbb" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to t('.news'), store_index_path, style: "color:#bbffbb" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to t('.contact'), store_index_path, style: "color:#bbffbb" %></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div id="search_bar" >
          <%= form_tag(store_index_path, method: :get) do %>
            <div class="search_bar_text">
              <%= text_field_tag :search, '', id: 'search_bar_text' %>
            </div>
            <div class="search_bar_image">
                <%= image_submit_tag 'search.png', id: 'search_bar_image'%>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color:#bbffbb;">Admin <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <% if session[:user_id] %>
              <li><%= link_to "Orders", orders_path%></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Products", products_path%></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path%></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Logout", logout_path, method: :delete%></li>
            <% else %>
              <li><%= link_to "Login", login_path%></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color:#bbffbb;">Language <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <% LANGUAGES.each do |language|%>
              <li><a href=""><%= link_to language[0].to_s, store_index_url(locale: language[1]) %></a></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I got most of this code from an example in the bootstrap documentation and have been implementing some erb into it to integrate it with my Rails project. The form class="navbar-form navbar-left" is where the search bar starts. The behavior I want is for this to fill up the remaining space between the unordered lists to the right and left and adjust its size based on the current screen size.

I have experimented with display flex and flex-grow, floating, & overflow. Cant seem to get anything working. I wont include my CSS file since its only some font/color changes, most of the CSS is from bootstrap anyways.

Any help/guidance is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap includes a [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options). Maybe you can use this to define the width of the search field.

The grid system divides the width into 12 columns. So you could use for example:

```html
.col-sm-12 .col-lg-4
```

You can play around with the values.

Comment: playing around with this some more, but this seems to resolve the issue. Thank you very much for your response!

Answer (score 2):

I'll ask the dumb question...  do you have the following in your < head > section?

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

without it, Bootstrap won't be responsive.

Comment: Yes, I have added this in the <head> section. Parts of the app are responsive just the search bar isnt. Was able to resolve this issue though. Thanks for the response!